# Change the web access log location for SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.6

Is it possible to change the web access log location for SonarQube (version 5.6.2) ?

I think we can enable/disable the web access logging  and change the log pattern using the sonar.properties file but I couldn't find a way to change the access log filename. Actually all I want is to send the access logs to stdout in my SonarQube docker container.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this question? I'm trying to do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Came across a mention of a `sonar.path.logs` property on: http://www.jouvinio.net/wiki/index.php/Configuration_Logs_SonarQube

Added this option to `conf/sonar.properties` and it worked successfully after sonar restart.

```
sonar.path.logs=/var/log/sonarqube
```

`[root@azsu-s-bi01sq1 failover]# ls -a /var/log/sonarqube/
.  ..  access.log  ce.log  es.log  sonar.log  web.log`